# How to handle error with Connect MongoDB Session ExpressJS Middleware

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, passport.js

I'm using PassportJS with express-session with connect-mongodb-session to handle sessions and store them in MongoDB. Here is my code, and it works fine:

```
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(session({
  store: new MongoStore({
    uri: 'mongodb://myConnectionString'
  }, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    };
  }),
  secret: 'mySecret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/api/auth', userRouter);
```

I'm trying to handle error here when I don't have a connection to my db. So when I turn my db off I'm getting the callback with error and can see this error in console.
But my problem is that my app still trying to make a request to /api/auth which should receive error in response, but server just hangs and not getting any of my routers after session middleware to handle requests.

I was wandering that it should be some (req, res, next) in express-session so I can send error to all requests when I have error in my callback. But I did not find solution. Now when I don't have connection to my db, server just hangs, giving me my error to console and not responding to all requests.

Comment: Are you handling errors in your userRouter? Also could you post snippet of the userRouter.